How to invoke a column from a table hosted in gcp and use that column as criterion for incremental load in another table using IICS
I have a table in oracle orc_tab_1 which i want to delta sync to gcp (let's say gcp_tab_1) using iics. for the delta sync i will fetch a col called last_sync_datetime from a different table hosted in gcp called gcp_tab_2 and on the basis of the orc_tab_1 col called created_dateime (condition as created_datetime > last_sync_datetime), the incremental load will happen. All of this using informatica only. Please need help!
i am able to get the value of the last_sync_datetime inside a temp table in oracle but i am not able to fetch that value to do the conditioning for incremental load
